# can't get value form service class in angular

Tags: angular

component.ts file
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { HistoryService } from '../../../../shared/history.service';
    import { Router } from "@angular/router";
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
    import { History } from '../../../../shared/history.model';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ins-history',
  templateUrl: './ins-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ins-history.component.css'],
  providers:[HistoryService]
})

export class InsHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public UserProfileService: HistoryService, private router: Router) { }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.HistoryList();
  }

  HistoryList()
  { let title = this.UserProfileService.Title;
      console.log(title);
      this.UserProfileService.getHistoryList(title).subscribe((res)=> {
      this.UserProfileService.history= res as History[];
      alert('ok');

    });
  }

}[historyservice.ts][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRRke.png

Comment: let title = this.UserProfileService.Title; not return any thing

Comment: you haven't assigned any value to `Title` inside your service when it is initialized, then why do you expect it to be 'defined'?

Comment: Could you try cleaning up your post a bit? It is a bit difficult to read in it's current state.